# C++ conditional ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, ternary

Lines 11, 12, 15 and 16 are getting errors: " invalid operands of types int and const char[2] to binary operator<< " (I removed the "`" so it wouldn't display it code format).

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int md,dg,dd,mg,m,d;
cin >> md >> dg >> dd >> mg;

if (dd+dg==md+mg){
   cout << (mg>dg) ? 0 : 1 << " ";
   cout << (dg>mg) ? 0 : 1 << endl;
}
else{
      cout << (mg+md>dd+dg) ? 0 : (dd+dg-mg-md) << " ";
      cout << (dg+dd>md+mg) ? 0 : (md+mg-dg-dd) << endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Watch out your operator precedence.

Comment: `1 << " "` isn't a valid expression; insert parens: `cout << ((mg>dg) ? 0 : 1) << " ";`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the ternary expression:

```
 cout << ((mg>dg) ? 0 : 1) << " ";
```

Otherwise the input is interpreted as

```
 cout << (mg>dg) ? 0 : (1 << " ");
```

due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! This has always been bugging me and I thought that it was time to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

All that you are missing is parenthesis around the ternary expression. Following is the fix.

cout << ((mg>dg) ? 0 : 1) << " ";

cout << ((dg>mg) ? 0 : 1) << endl;

cout << ((mg+md>dd+dg) ? 0 : (dd+dg-mg-md)) << " ";

cout << ((dg+dd>md+mg) ? 0 : (md+mg-dg-dd)) << endl;

Answer (score 0):

It should be : `cout<<((mg>dg)?0:1)<<endl` and similarly for others.